Regex to get all strings between +
I have following file content
NAD+DP+++Test GmbH & Co. KG:Filiale Test:Test+Groß Test Straße 96-98+Berlin++13452+DE'

and i want to get all the strings between the + segments. Even if they are empty. Any ideas? We tried it with [A-Za-z0-9\ß\p{L}&amp;.-] but with that we don't get all string seperated.

You are missing a few characters [A-Za-z0-9\ß\p{L}&.:' -]+ or [^+\r\n]+ https://regex101.com/r/paYzfF/1

(?<![^+])[^+\n]*
10 matches
0-3 NAD
4-6 DP
7-7 empty string
8-8 empty string
9-45    Test GmbH & Co. KG:Filiale Test:Test
46-68   Groß Test Straße 96-98
69-75   Berlin
76-76   empty string
77-82   13452
83-86   DE'


awesome . . . . @Sigma

(?<![^+])[^+\n]*,  I think \n not required here @Sigma if required, can you explain it ?

I'm not sure what bastion expect when there's linebreak in the text, assuming he does not like them in the result.

Ya, that's right ...

Hi Sigma, first of all thanks for the help back then. It worked. Now i have another problem that the customer has a ?+ as placeholder in there names. So i need a regex which doesn't split the segment when there's a ? before the +. Do you have any idea?

With XPath 2.0 or later it sounds as if you want to use tokenize e.g. tokenize('NAD+DP+++Test GmbH & Co. KG:Filiale Test:Test+Groß Test Straße 96-98+Berlin++13452+DE', '\+') to get a sequence of strings, like NAD, DP, ""..., see the 10 complete results at the XPath 3.1 fiddle.
